# How to know the exception type for std::exception

Tags: c++, exception

I have a try-catch block like below

```
try
{
   // Do something here.
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
   // std exception. 
}
catch(...)
{
    // Unknown exception. We can't know the type.
}
```

I am reading some documentation from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/ but to me it is not obvious how to know what exception type was caught when the code goes into the std::exception part.

Is there a way to get a string with the type of error? (I don't want to surface the error message, just the exception type)

Comment: You can only specify which exception types you *expect*. You can't get the concrete type of the exception. You would need to implement this behavior into your own exception type.

Comment: I see.. so no way to do this similarly to how this is done on C# with the getType function, right?

Comment: C++'s type reflection features are very limited compared to C#. The closest thing may be [`type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) but the name you get is platform dependent and not very useful except for printing or logging. Edit : Looks like @Brian's answer covers this.

Comment: Yeah, this is for logging purposes so I think that would do the trick. Trying to figure out how this works though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a string with the type of error?

Sort of. If you catch by reference (as you are doing in the above code), then you can apply `typeid` to the exception to get some info about its dynamic type. This is made possible by the fact that `std::exception` is a polymorphic type. However, there's no guarantee that `std::type_info::name()` is a readable name for the type.

Comment: Maybe this is asking so much but would you add an example on how to use typeid from std::type_info::name() ?

Comment: @user3587624: `std::cout << typeid(e).name();`

Answer (score 3):

You can catch different exceptions with different `catch` blocks:

```
try
{
   // Do something here.
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& e) 
{
   // Handle runtime error
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& e) 
{
   // Handle out of range
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
   // Handle all other exceptions 
}
catch(...)
{
    // Unknown exception. We can't know the type.
}
```

Of course it does not always make sense to have a seperate catch for every type of exception, so you still would need a way to tell what is the type of the exception within the `catch(std::exception&)` block, for which I refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59312767/4117728).